# tkinter on enthought canopy (Windows)

Tags: python, tkinter, enthought

tkinter is supposed to be installed with standard python, but on my windows 8.1 computer (using enthought Canopy), I get the following error. I just updated everything.

```
import tkinter
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b98d59735c04> in <module>()
----> 1 import tkinter

ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works now.  I am using 2.7, but the tutorial I was copying was using 3.

Comment: @axm302: Please note http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235

Answer (score 3):

I am going to make my comment into an answer for any future readers.

You are using Python 2.x.  In this version, the Tkinter library is named `Tkinter`, not `tkinter`.  The lowercase `tkinter` is Python 3.x's name for the library.

Simply replace your import line with:

```
import Tkinter
```

and the problem will be solved.

Keep in mind though  that this is the Python 2.x library, so some 3.x features will not be available.